# Correct use of fun.data with stat_summary in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

From ?stat_summary.

> fun.data : Complete summary function. Should take data frame as input
>   and return data frame as output

I'm having trouble understanding this.  It doesn't seem like my summary function `so.summary` is being passed a data frame at all!

Code:

```
set.seed(0)
so.example <- data.frame(
  sampleID=rep(1:15)
  , sales=runif(15, 0, 1)*1000
  , revenue=runif(15, 0, 1)*10000
)

so.summary <- function(z) {
  print(z)
  data.frame(sales=median(z$sales), revenue=median(z$revenue))
}

ggplot(
  so.example
  , aes(x=sales, y=revenue)
  ) + geom_point() + stat_summary(fun.data=so.summary, geom='point', color='red')
```

Output:

```
[1] 2672.207
Error in z$sales : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: According to this [ggplot2 issue](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/929) the documentation is wrong - the function only gets a single vector, but it can return a data frame. It seems that Hadley only updated [this part](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/commit/1cdf2339ca98d8732427640015f35867ae6da20d) of the documentation and forgot about the part you quoted above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fun.data` summarises `y` at each `x`.  It takes a vector of the `y` values as input.

One use case is for mapping different summary statistics to different aesthetics:

```
set.seed(0)
week <- floor(runif(30, 1, 5))
sales <- week * runif(30, 0, 1)*10000
so.example <- data.frame(week=week, sales=sales)

so.summary <- function(y) {
  return(data.frame(y=median(y), size=length(y), alpha=sd(y)/10000))
}

ggplot(
  so.example
  , aes(x=week, y=sales)
) + geom_point() + stat_summary(fun.data=so.summary, geom='point', colour='red')
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you really want to use stat summary to plot that summary point. As logworthy noted, `fun.data` will receive a `y` vector for every unique `x` value. More broadly, it splits up the aesthetics `data.frame` for each unique `x` value (we'll use this fact later).But, if you move around your aesthetics, you can let `stat_summary` see the entire revenue vector.

```
ggplot(so.example) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=sales, y=revenue)) + 
  stat_summary(aes(x= median(sales), y= revenue), fun.y= median, geom= 'point', color= 'red')
```

Now, `stat_summary` can 'see' only 1 `x` aesthetic and the entire `y` vector in the `fun.y` input.

If that's not *fun* enough, you can trick `fun.data` into seeing other vectors of your frame, for example, let's say you needed a weighted mean instead of a median.

```
set.seed(0)
so.example <- data.frame(
  sampleID=rep(1:15)
  , sales=runif(15, 0, 1)*1000
  , revenue=runif(15, 0, 1)*10000
  , weight= runif(15, 0, 1)
)

so.mean.weight <- function(x, wt){ sum(x*wt)/sum(wt) }
```

I created a simple weight function, but, could easily grab `weighted.mean` from `stats` (more importantly, the function is clearly arbitrary as long as it returns 1 value for the inputs).

The trick for `fun.data` to see other vectors in the `data.frame` is to grab extra aesthetics from the `parent.frame()` while in the function. This is pretty hacky as you'll get warning messages. Let's take a look at the new `stat_summary` call:

```
stat_summary(
    aes(x= so.mean.weight(sales, weight), y= revenue, wt= weight) 
    , fun.data= so.summary
    , geom= 'point'
    , color= 'darkgreen'
    , size= 2
    )
```

Notice the input in the `aes`, `wt= weight`. In `geom_point`, there is no wt aesthetic (you want to choose something that you know is not an aesthetic name (foo/bar would have done just as well), so, you'll get a nice warning message telling you it will be ignored. It will be ignored, but not removed/deleted.

With that in mind, let's take a look inside the new `so.summary` function:

```
so.summary <- function(z) {
  # Grab aesthetic DF
  aesDF <- parent.frame()$df
  print(names(aesDF)) # returns input aesthetic vectors: "x", "y", "group", and "wt"
  pnt <- data.frame(y= so.mean.weight(z, aesDF$wt ) )
  print(pnt)
  pnt
}
```

You can see the call to the `parent.frame()$df` grants you access to the aesthetic vectors to use in your calculations.